# F# constructors and classes: Set up classes without extra mutable variables for each member property

Tags: f#

So I have been looking at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd233192.aspx) page on the MSDN   about constructors in F#.
I am looking at the very first code sample

```
type MyClass(x0, y0, z0) =
    let mutable x = x0
    let mutable y = y0
    let mutable z = z0
    do
        printfn "Initialized object that has coordinates (%d, %d, %d)" x y z
    member this.X with get() = x and set(value) = x <- value
    member this.Y with get() = y and set(value) = y <- value
    member this.Z with get() = z and set(value) = z <- value
    new() = MyClass(0, 0, 0)
```

Is there a way to set this up without a mutable let binding for every property you have?

I am asking because my class has lots of variables. And worse yet, I am thinking about adding way more.

Here is an example.

```
    type lineSet (x1off,x2off,y1off,y2off,x1,x2,y1,y2,rot,rotOff,count) =
        member x1Offset with get() = x10ff and set(value) = x1Offset <- value
        member x2Offset with get() = x20ff and set(value) = x2Offset <- value
        member y1Offset with get() = y10ff and set(value) = y1Offset <- value
        member y2Offset with get() = y20ff and set(value) = y2Offset <- value

        member x1Start with get() =x1Start and set(value) = x1Start <- value
        member x2Start
        member y1Start
        member y2Start

        member rotation
        member rotationOffset

        member lineCount
        member SVG_Representation
        member XAML_Representation
```

Having to add a mutable let binding for each one of these properties would be highly unpreferable. It would essentially double the number of variables in my class.

Is there some kind of reduced syntax for having a constructor that assigns all of its parameters to the corresponding properties?

Also, this line of code:

```
   member x1Offset with get() = x10ff and set(value) = x1Offset <- value
```

does not produce any errors. That being said, I am not sure if it does what I hope it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this syntax

```
type MyClass(property1 : int) =
    member val Property1 = property1
    member val Property2 = "" with get, set
```

Taken from [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd483467.aspx)

Comment: What is the proper syntax to combine both of those lines for just one variable? I.e. member val Property1 = property1 with get, set.

Comment: @AlexanderRyanBaggett - `member val Property1 = property1 with get, set` works just fine for me

Comment: One last question: What does my last line of code there on my question actually do? (if anything)

Comment: @AlexanderRyanBaggett - creates a property were the setter doesn't affect the value returned by the getter.  This is probably a bad idea.